# Suggest me some good references for sonification

Tags: signal-analysis

I need good reference books/tutorials/doccumentations on sonification.

Please suggest me some books or other references from which I can learn about sonification and algorithms of sonification.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the references list on the [Wikipedia page on sonification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonification) is of use for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

Proceedings of annual International Conference on Auditory Display. The annual ICAD conference is the prime forum for academia and industry to exchange ideas and discuss developments in the field of auditory display.

https://smartech.gatech.edu/handle/1853/49750

2)

http://sonification.de/handbook/

This book is a comprehensive introductory presentation of the key research areas in the interdisciplinary fields of sonification and auditory display. Chapters are written by leading experts, providing a wide-range coverage of the central issues, and can be read from start to finish, or dipped into as required (like a smorgasbord menu).